# matrix of EditText in android

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext

How do I create a matrix of EditTexts? After applying this code I get all the fields in one line, but it should look like a table based on the number of rows and columns. The code:

```
public void addFields() {

    int rows = getInt(numbRows);
    int cols = getInt(numbColumns);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayoutMatrix);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    EditText editText[][] = new EditText[rows][cols];

   for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {          
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            editText[i][j] = new EditText(this);
            editText[i][j].setWidth(50);
            layout.setLayoutParams(params);
            layout.addView(editText[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out the documentation for [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html)

Comment: Use [`GridLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayout.html)